# Is there a way to analyze the impact/correlation of categorical variables to the label in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, stat

The dataset I have is a lot larger than this (about 3000 rows * 50 columns), I'm just going to put a sample here. It's a dataframe including information for every line. Basically, I intended to analyze the attribute of each label, like `Level 3` might have a higher annual income; or what contribute to higher level. What statistical functions might be a good fit to analyze it? I'm trying with `sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()` to labelize every category variable and trying something like `stats.chi2.ppf()` or correlation matrix. Not sure if they work out in my case.

```
example = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Degree": ['Graduate', 'Undergraduate', 'Undergraduate', 'Graduate', 'Undergraduate', 'Doctorate'],
        "Age": ['Age 26-35','Age 18-25','Age 18-25','Age 18-25', 'Age 26-35', 'Older than 35'],
        "Location": ['VA','DC','DC','CA','DC','MA'],
        "Gender": ['male','male','female','male','male','female'],
        "Annual Income": ['\$5,001 - \$10,000','<$5,000','\$15,001 - \$25,000','>\$50,000','<\$5,000','\$15,001 - \$25,000'],
        "Level": [0,1,2,0,0,3],
    }
)

Degree  Age Location    Gender  Annual Income   Level
0   Graduate    Age 26-35   VA  male    $5,001 - $10,000    0
1   Undergraduate   Age 18-25   DC  male    <$5,000 1
2   Undergraduate   Age 18-25   DC  female  $15,001 - $25,000   2
3   Graduate    Age 18-25   CA  male    >$50,000    0
4   Undergraduate   Age 26-35   DC  male    <$5,000 0
5   Doctorate   Older than 35   MA  female  $15,001 - $25,000   3
```

Open to any ideas and comments.

Answer (score 0):

In the correlation I suggest use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/).

> Heatmaps are used to show relationships between two variables, one
> plotted on each axis. By observing how cell colors change across each
> axis, you can observe if there are any patterns in value for one or
> both variables.
>
> https://chartio.com/learn/charts/heatmap-complete-guide/

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(example[['Level']])
```

[image]

However for heatmap - there is need for having integer - so **Annual Income** and **Age** can be transformed into integer.

There is some approximation (getting first number from income & age - not range - also there can be use. .mean()):

```
example['Income'] = example['Annual Income'].str.extract('(\d+)')
example['Age'] = example['Age'].str.extract('(\d+)')
example['Income'] = pd.to_numeric(example['Income'])
example['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(example['Age'])


import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(example[['Level', 'Income', 'Age']])
```

[image]

When the **annual income** and **age** is integer - there is also option for .corr() function:

```
example.corr()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
example = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Degree": ['Graduate', 'Undergraduate', 'Undergraduate', 'Graduate', 'Undergraduate', 'Doctorate'],
        "Age": ['Age 26-35','Age 18-25','Age 18-25','Age 18-25', 'Age 26-35', 'Older than 35'],
        "Location": ['VA','DC','DC','CA','DC','MA'],
        "Gender": ['male','male','female','male','male','female'],
        "Annual Income": ['\$5,001 - \$10,000','<$5,000','\$15,001 - \$25,000','>\$50,000','<\$5,000','\$15,001 - \$25,000'],
        "Level": [0,1,2,0,0,3],
    }
)
unique_items = []
for key in example:
    unique_items.append(example[key].unique())
for item in unique_items:
    print(item)
# figure out how to sort each unique item,
# for example, degree= by more education
#              income = ascending
#              level = ascending , etc
# now use the index as the value and you can start to do math and pictures
# Analyze for me means:
# Now what you would do is pick any two and scatterplot it to see if there is a relationship
# then pick all pairs for any one and make a collage of thumbnail scatterplots
# then measure correlation or other math properties that put them in groupings you like
# think of this like categorizing galaxies, 
# straight lines sloping up is one type that would be high on the list
# but randomness is another type and some might look like butterflies
# then sort by correlation and groupings to show all the strongest top 100 list
# good luck ;)
```